# Vuetify - how to reset the child component in the v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i added Create component to v-dialog and i want the Create component reset when the v-dialog closes. How can i do?

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="800">
           <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-btn depressed color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" @click="dialog = true">
                 <v-icon color="white">mdi-plus-thick</v-icon>
                 <span class="ml-2">Cihaz Ekle</span>
              </v-btn>
           </template>
           <Create />
        </v-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `v-if` on your component with the value used for toggle the dialog:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="800">
       <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn depressed color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" @click="dialog = true">
             <v-icon color="white">mdi-plus-thick</v-icon>
             <span class="ml-2">Cihaz Ekle</span>
          </v-btn>
       </template>
       <Create v-if="dialog"/>
    </v-dialog>
```